# How do I use one object's method to update a variable in another object?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am not sure if I worded the question correctly, however, I have code to detail it. Firstly, I have a class Class1:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public var S:Number = 0;
    public function Class1() 
    {   
    }
}
```

Which I am using to create an object in my document class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public var class1:Class1 = new Class1;
    public var class2:Class2 = new Class2;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        trace(String(class1.S));
        class2.c2f1(true, class1.S);
        trace(String(class1.S));
    }
}
```

And I want to update that object's variable S through another object's method c2f1 created from this class:

```
public class Class2 
{
    public function Class2() 
    {   
    }

    public function c2f1(param1:Boolean, f1:Number):void
    {
        if (param1) f1 = 1;
        trace("c2f1")
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0
c2f1
0
```

Where it ideally should be:

```
0
c2f1
1
```

This isn't the actual code I am using for any projects, I have specified the problem in hopes that I may more easily see the concepts involved.

Hope someone can help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it's not the variable of `class1.S` that's incremented but a copy of it - in AS3, simple types are passed by value - that is, Flash creates a copy of the variable and that's what's passed to the called function.

You can pass your object to this function:

```
...
public function c2f1(param1:Boolean, obj:Class1):void
{
    if (param1) obj.S = 1;
    trace("c2f1")
}
```

If you need to pass multiple different object types, you can create an interface instead and pass that. Then your `Class1` class can implement that interface and you can call a function through that interface to increment the value.

When you pass your `Class1` instance, it gets passed by reference because it's a complex type, so you can modify its member variables.

Alternatively, your function can just return 1 or 0 and then you can assign that to `S`:

```
...
public function c2f1(param1:Boolean):int
{
    trace("c2f1")
    return ( param1 ? 1 : 0 );
}

...
var o1:Class1 = new Class1 ();
var o2:Class2 = new Class2 ();

o1.S = o2.c2f1(bValue);
```